# How to get Meteor.absoluteUrl() to return https?

Tags: meteor

My website is hosted under https, but `Meteor.absoluteUrl()` still returns `http://…`.

It seems, like it's not happens automatically.

How to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl) there is an option to generate an https URL.

The call would look like:

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl('your_custom_path', {secure: true});
```